# What the difference between lightweight concurrency and heavyweight concurrency?

Tags: multithreading

I just learn multiple threading programming, but the question here is a very basic concept need to be clarified first of all.

As I searched from internet, what i understand is Heavyweight is regarding to "process", and Lightweight maps to "thread". However, why process is heavyweight? because of non-sharing memory or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Heavyweight" concurrency is where each of the concurrent executors is expensive to start and/or has large overheads.

"Lightweight" concurrency is where each of the concurrent executors is cheap to start and/or has small overheads.

Processes are generally more expensive to manage for the OS than threads, since each process needs an independent address space and various management structures, whereas threads within a process share these structures.

Consequently, processes are considered heavyweight, whereas threads are lightweight.

However, in some contexts, threads are considered heavyweight, and the "lightweight" concurrency facility is some kind of "task". In these contexts, the runtime will typically execute these tasks on a pool of threads, suspending them when they block, and reusing the threads for other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the "heavy" classification no longer carries the same weight as it used to while the advantage of process separation has lost none of its potency ;-)

This is all thanks to the copy-on-write semantics; during a `fork()` the pages from the parent are no longer blindly copied for the child process. Both processes can operate using shared memory until the child process starts to write into one of the shared memory pages.

Of course, creating more processes has a higher tendency of being limited by the operating system as process ids are a more limited resource than threads.